# VPython 6 - Object won't delete

Tags: python, python-2.7, vpython

I have a 3D elastic collision simulation. I'd like to clear all of the sphere objects from my program from a button press. The documentation indicates that I should do the following:

```
def clear_balls():
   for ball in balls:
      ball.visible = False
      del ball
```

This successfully makes the balls invisible in the scene, but they still take up memory and collide with balls that still exist. I want it completely removed. Trying this with a unique ball name this isn't part of a list as some have suggested still results in the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`del ball` is not doing what you think because `balls` still holds a reference to the object.  You need to empty the `balls` list:

```
def clear_balls():
    for ball in balls:
        ball.visible = False
     balls[:] = []
```